# Php while loop not working, Strange error

Tags: php, while-loop

Here is my php:

```
<?
  $i = 0;

  function f() {
  $i++;
  echo $i;
  if ($i < 3) {
    return true;
  }
}

while(f())
?>
```

I was expecting output to be `123`

But I get this:

```
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in exp.php on line 5
```

Comment: you're not returning false anywhere.

Comment: not necessary. if nothing is returned, it defaults to null which evaluates to false. However my eyes look for something to return for more readability :)

Comment: Try `$f = function() use($i) {...}` and then `while($f())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$i` variable inside your function is a local variable (of that function). If you want to access the variable(s) outside the function, use `global`. This has to do with the [variable scope](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

```
<?php
$i = 0;

function f() {
    global $i;
    $i++;
    echo $i;
    if ($i < 3) return true;
    return false;
}

while(f());
```

It is also good practice to make sure you return a value on all code paths (and not rely on the the defaults).

Comment: This worked, I didn't realize that a locally defined variable would override a global var with the same name, interesting, Thanks.

Comment: @andrew Also read about [variable scope](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) on php.net ;-).

Comment: `if ($i < 3) return true; return false;` can be shortened to `return ($i < 3);`

Comment: @n.st : yes I know. However, for less experienced people, it's less readable and clear what happens there.

Answer (score 4):

$i is not defined in function's scope. Everytime it resets to zero.

```
$i = 0;

function f() {
    global $i;
    $i++;
    echo $i;
    return $i<3; //thanks @styxxy
}

while (f());
```

Answer (score 0):

$i is a global variable, declared outside of the function.  The other $i is a local variable, it has a storage location but no initial value.  If you want to refer to the global variable from within the function, add the global keyword...

Answer (score 0):

i is a global variable right? 
i think you should make it known to the function f().
Like this

```
global $i;
```

Answer (score -1):

Why not just:

```
$i = 0;

while($i<3){
    $i++;
    f($i);
}

function f($i){
    echo $i;
}
```